# Getting $3$ (but not $4$) of the same in a row at least twice when flipping $100$ coins

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

> $100$ coins are flipped. What is the probability of getting $3$ of the
> same in a row **at least twice**, but not $4$ of the same in a row?

I tried using recursion, but I am having trouble finding the relation to the previous one. I think there's a better solution.

Comment: @EkeshKumar I don't think so. How would you apply PIE here? What would be the sets?

Comment: At least twice or exactly twice?

Comment: @saulspatz At least twice. Although a solution involving exactly twice is also welcomed, but I think it's harder.

Answer (score 1):

Recurrence is the only way I've been able to do this.  It's a little tricky, because we can't confine our attention solely to strings of heads and tails that meet the criteria.

Call a string of H and T a $0$-string if it has no occurrences of either HHH or TTT.  Let

- $a_n$ be the number of $n$-character $0$-strings that end in HT,
- $b_n$ be the number of $n$-character $0$-strings that end in TH,
- $c_n$ be the number of $n$-character $0$-strings that end in TT, and
- $d_n$ be the number of $n$-character $0$-strings that end in HH.

By symmetry, $a_n=b_n$ and $c_n=d_n$

We have $$a_{n+1}=b_n+d_n= a_n+c_n,\tag1$$

since we can add a T to any $0$-string that ends in H to get a $0$ string that  ends in HT, and all $0$-strings that end in HT arise in this way.  We have also $$c_{n+1}=a_n\tag2$$ because if we add a $T$ to a string that ends in TT, we will no longer have a $0$-string.

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $$a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1},\ n\geq3$$  We have $a_2=1,\ a_3=2$ and we see $$c_{n+1}=a_n= F_n\tag3$$ where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Call a string of H and T a $1$-string if it has exactly one occurrence of either HHH or TTT, and no occurrence of either HHHH or TTTT.  Let

- $e_n$ be the number of $n$-character $1$-strings that end in HT,
- $f_n$ be the number of $n$-character $1$-strings that end in TH,
- $g_n$ be the number of $n$-character $1$-strings that end in HTT,
- $h_n$ be the number of $n$-character $1$-strings that end in THH,
- $i_n$ be the number of $n$-character $1$-strings that end in TTT and
- $k_n$ be the number of $n$-character $1$-strings that end in HHH.

We have $e_n=f_n$, $g_n=h_n$, $i_n=k_n$ by symmetry.

As above, we get $$\begin{align}
e_{n+1}&=f_n+h_n+k_n\\
e_{n+1}&=e_n+g_n+i_n\\
g_{n+1}&=e_n\\
i_{n+1}&=c_n=F_n
\end{align}$$ The last equation expresses the fact that to get a $1$-string ending in TTT, we must add a T to a $0$-string ending in TT.  This gives
$$e_{n+1}=e_n+e_{n-1}+F_{n-2}\tag4$$ for $n\geq 5$.

Call a string of H and T a $2$-string if it has *at least* two occurrences of either HHH or TTT, and no occurrence of either HHHH or TTTT.  Let

- $p_n$ be the number of $n$-character $2$-strings that end in HT,
- $q_n$ be the number of $n$-character $2$-strings that end in TH,
- $r_n$ be the number of $n$-character $2$-strings that end in HTT,
- $s_n$ be the number of $n$-character $2$-strings that end in THH,
- $t_n$ be the number of $n$-character $2$-strings that end in TTT, and
- $u_n$ be the number of $n$-character $2$-strings that end in HHH.

We have $p_n=q_n$, $r_n=s_n$, $t_n=u_n$ by symmetry.

We get $$\begin{align}
p_{n+1}&=q_n+s_n+u_n\\
p_{n+1}&=p_n+r_n+t_n\\
r_{n+1}&=p_n\\
t_{n+1}&=r_n+g_n
\end{align}$$
because we can get a $2$-string ending in TTT either by adding a T at the end of a $2$-string ending in HTT, or at the end of a $1$-string ending in HTT.

Observe that the total number of $2$-strings of length $n$ is $$T_n:=2p_n+2r_n+2t_n=2p_{n+1}$$

We have $$\begin{align}
p_{n+1}&=p_n+r_n+t_n\\
&=p_n+p_{n-1}+r_{n-1}+g_{n-1}\\
&=p_n+p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}+e_{n-2}\tag5
\end{align}$$

or $$T_n=T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}+T_{n-3}+2e_{n-2}\tag6$$

With initial data, $$
F_0=0,\ F_1=1\\
e_0=e_1=e_2=e_3=0,\ e_4=1,\ e_5=2 \\
T_0=T_1=T_2=T_3=T_4=T_5=0,\ T_6=2$$
and formulas $(4)$ and $(6)$, I have checked the values produced by the recurrence against a brute-force count of $2$-strings, up through $n=20$.

Carrying through the recurrence gave me $$T_{100}=360772317646371359457234176$$ which results in a probability of success of $$\boxed{0.0002845991770771989}$$

It should be possible, at least in theory, to find a closed-form expression for $T_n$.  Equation $(4)$ is a second-order linear recurrence, with constant coefficients, and $F_n$ has a well-known formula as a linear combination of two exponentials, so we should be able to solve $(4)$ completely, and we expect a solution in the form of a linear combination of exponentials.  Then equation $(6)$ is of the same type as equation $(4)$, expect that it is third-order rather than second-order.  [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E3-x%5E2-x-1%3D0) will solve the characteristic equation exactly, but the roots look unpleasant.  I wouldn't want to try it without a CAS.

I did notice however, that near $n=100$, we have $$\frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}\approx1.8393$$ which is very close to the real root found by WolframAlpha.  It shouldn't be hard to get a good empirical formula for $T_n$.

**EDIT**

It occurred to me that there is a better way of approaching the problem of finding a closed-form solution.

From $(4)$ we have $$\begin{align}
e_{n+3}&=e_{n+2}+e_{n+1}+F_{n}\\
-e_{n+2}&=-e_{n+1}-e_{n}-F_{n-1}\\
-e_{n+1}&=-e_{n}-e_{n-1}-F_{n-3}\\
\end{align}$$

Adding these equations gives $$e_{n+3}-2e_{n+2}-e_{n+1}+2e_n+e_{n-1}=F_n-F_{n-1}-F_{n-2}=0\tag7$$ so that $e_n$ satisfies a homogeneous linear recurrence.

Now we can try a similar procedure with equation $(6)$ .  We have $$\begin{bmatrix}
.5 &-.5 &-.5 &-.5&0&0&0&0\\
0&-1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&-.5&+.5&+.5&+.5&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&-1&-1&-1&0\\
0&0&0&0&.5&-.5&-.5&-.5
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
T_{n+5}\\
T_{n+4}\\
T_{n+3}\\
T_{n+2}\\
T_{n+1}\\
T_{n}\\
T_{n-1}\\
T_{n-2}\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
e_{n+3}\\
-2e_{n+2}\\
-e_{n+1}\\
2e_n\\
e_{n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Adding these $(5)$ equations, and clearing fractions gives $$T_{n+5}-3T_{n+4}+4T_{n+2}+2T_{n+1}-2T_n-3T_{n-1}-T_{n-2}=0\tag8$$
This recurrence has characteristic polynomial
$$x^7-3x^6+4x^4+2x^3-2x^2-3x-1=(x^2-x-1)^2(x^3-x^2-x-1),$$ so that [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E7-3x%5E6%2B4x%5E4%2B2x%5E3-2x%5E2-3x-1%3D0) is able to solve it exactly.

This still seems to require a CAS, but at least we have a homogeneous recurrence, so there's no need to guess a particular solution.  I may try to do this with sympy tomorrow.